# Which standard Salesforce objects are supported for Path settings?

Tags: path, salespath

In my Salesforce Org I want to setup a Path for a [Shipment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_shipment.htm) standard Salesforce object. However in `Setup > User interface > Path settings` I cannot setup a path for `Shipment` objects - the object is not available in the picklist of objects when creating a new path.

My checks so far

- Path settings are activated in the Org (I have a path configured for another object already)
- Shipment object has no RecordTypes configured (but other object with configured path doesn't have RecordTypes either)
- I have admin rights access to the `Shipment`
- The `Shipment` object has a Status picklist field valid for a path journey

**Are there any limitations on which Salesforce standard objects are supported for Path settings and if yes where can I find a list of supported objects?**

The list on Salesforce help page on [Guide Users with Path](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.path_overview.htm&type=5) doesn't seem to be complete, since e.g. the `ProductRequest` standard object I am already using for path is not listed and my dropdown list of objects when creating a new path is much longer. Also custom objects seem to be fully supported?